# default menu option

Tags: jquery, menu, tabs

how can I make this menu here have the default be the "about" tab?

http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/examples/horizontal-subnav/

so when your mouse isnt hovering over any of them, its on the about tab?

Answer (score 1):

I'd give the about `<li>` a class for this, maybe `class="default"`, making it easy to change later.  Then, just change the hover function to account for this:

```
$("ul#topnav li").unbind().hover(function() {
  $(this).css({ 'background' : '#1376c9 url(topnav_active.gif) repeat-x'})
         .find("span").show();
  $(this).siblings('li').css({ 'background' : 'none'}).find("span").hide();
} , function() {
  if($(this).hasClass('default')) return;
  $(this).css({ 'background' : 'none'})
         .find("span").hide();
  $(this).siblings('.default').mouseenter();
});
```

[You can view a demo of it here](http://jsfiddle.net/dXpt6/), if you want it shown when the page initially loads as well, you can do this:

```
$("ul#topnav li.default").mouseenter();
```

I'm not sure how you're using this in your site, but I'd put the hover styles into a `.hover` class, and then you can do:

- [`.addClass('hover')`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) instead of `.css({ 'background' : '#1376c9 ...})`
- [`.removeClass('hover')`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) instead of `.css({ 'background' : 'none'})`
  ​

Answer (score 0):

Something like

`$("ul#topnav li:nth-child(2)").find("span").show();`

Will get the 2nd `li` from the `<ul id="nav">` and display the span block below it.